# ORA-02291: integrity constraint error when i try add data

Tags: sql, oracle, count, oracle-apex, integrity

I am using Oracle Apex to create a case management system. In my Cases table I want 3 column which counts how many exhibits, tasks and notes a case has. I have tried referencing the exhibit, task and note tables as foreign keys in the case table then in the apex application builder I will use the query

```
SELECT COUNT (CASE_ID) FROM Exhibit WHERE CASE_ID = CASE_ID;
```

These are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Exhibit(
    Exhibit_id int PRIMARY KEY,
    Case_id int,
    Exhibit_Analyst VARCHAR(30),
    Exhibit_Type    VARCHAR(40),
    Exhibit_Priority    VARCHAR(5),
    Exhibit_Description VARCHAR(500),
    Date_Seized DATE,
    Exhibit_Location    VARCHAR(50));

CREATE TABLE Task(
    Task_id int PRIMARY KEY,
    Case_id int,
    Task_Name   VARCHAR(30),
    Task_Description VARCHAR(500),
    Task_Start_Date TIMESTAMP,  
    Task_Deadline TIMESTAMP,
    Task_Status VARCHAR(20));

CREATE TABLE Note(
    Note_id int PRIMARY KEY,
    Case_id int,
    Note_Timestamp  TIMESTAMP,
    Note    VARCHAR(500));

CREATE TABLE Analyst(
    Analyst_id  int PRIMARY KEY,
    Analyst_Name    VARCHAR(30),
    Analyst_dob DATE);

CREATE TABLE Case(
    Case_ID int PRIMARY KEY,
    Case_Name VARCHAR(50),
    Case_Type   VARCHAR(20),
    Analyst_Name VARCHAR(50),
    Case_Started    TIMESTAMP,
    Last_Modified   TIMESTAMP,
    Case_Status VARCHAR(15),
    Exhibit_id int REFERENCES Exhibit(Exhibit_id),
    Task_id int REFERENCES Task(Task_id),
    Note_id int REFERENCES Note(Note_id));
```

When I try to insert a row in the app it returns this error

> ORA-02291: integrity constraint (TOBY.SYS_C0091649974) violated -
>   parent key not found

I have definitely done something wrong, any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Insert a row into which table?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to add value in table (with Foreign Key) which has no matching value in table(with Primary Key).

To solve this: you need to add the value to the table with primary key and then insert value in foreign table.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to insert? Post your insert statement

Alternatively, check what that constraint does. Check `search_condition` from below query

```
    select 
    constraint_name, 
    table_name, 
    case constraint_type 
        when 'C' then 'check constraint on a table'
        when 'P' then 'primary key'
        when 'U' then 'unique key'
        when 'R' then 'referential integrity'
        when 'V' then 'with check option, on a view'
        when 'O' then 'with read only, on a view'
    end constraint_definition,
    search_condition
     from all_constraints
    where owner = 'TOBY'
    and constraint_name = 'SYS_C0091649974'
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

check which tables have this constraint:

```
SELECT C.OWNER, 
       A.TABLE_NAME,
       A.COLUMN_NAME,
       A.CONSTRAINT_NAME,
       -- referenced pk
       C.R_OWNER,
       C_PK.TABLE_NAME R_TABLE_NAME,
       C_PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME R_PK
  FROM ALL_CONS_COLUMNS A
       JOIN ALL_CONSTRAINTS C ON A.OWNER = C.OWNER 
  AND A.CONSTRAINT_NAME = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME
       JOIN ALL_CONSTRAINTS C_PK ON C.R_OWNER = C_PK.OWNER 
  AND C.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME = C_PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
 WHERE C.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'R' AND A.CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'SYS_C0091649974';
```

In order to remedy this error, you will need to insert the value that you attempted to place in the child table into the parent table first. Once inserted as a parent row, you can go back and insert the value into the child table.